# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when creating a file from Async task

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a new jpeg file from an async task. The relevent code snippet is shown below

```
private async void OnSocketConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
   await ReceiveFile(args);
}

private async Task ReceiveFile(StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
  string pathString = @"C:\Users\sarav\test.jpg";
  FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(pathString, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
}
```

It throws the System.UnauthorizedAccessException above in FileStream. The same Filestream snippet for the same path is working on a console based C# application, in the sense the file test.jpg is getting created. Any suggestions as of what i am missing here.

Comment: check and see if your file "test.jpg" already exists on the disk.

Comment: `await Task.Run(() => ReceiveFile(args));`

Comment: Tried this also, same exception is being thrown

Comment: your code executes fine on my machine.  try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706467/access-to-the-path-denied-error-in-c-sharp  or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304191/access-to-the-path-c-users-xxx-desktop-is-denied

Comment: Even for me as a standalone app it works fine. Since the context is from a  callback, is that making a difference here?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are trying to create a file under different user. See what you have in the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in both scenarios before you do `new FileStream`.

Since you don't have an exact code and environment setup in the question, I cannot propose an exact solution, but can give a direction to dig into. If you have a different user, just make sure that it has an access to particular directory you need.

Comment: I am logged into my windows 10 laptop using my gmail account, which has admin privileges. Shouldnt that be fine?

Comment: Also regarding Thread.CurrentPrincipal, i am watching this in my debugger. Can you please tell me which field int hat structure i need to look for?

Comment: You can look at `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` to see which Windows user you are running under.

Comment: I am unable to view any of these variables since i guess its an asynchronous task?. The debugger shows as not foudn with red cross marks. Also one more observation if i try to create the file from the UI thread context, then i get a different exception "Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread. Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run."

Comment: If i put it in this code block i get Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread var task = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                

                await ReceiveFile(args);
            });

Comment: I feel the issue is since i am trying to create the file from a callback handler, the handler doesn't have any user credential context hence the permission issue. Is there a a solution to this, since i need to create the file once i get the socket call back called