# Unable to zip folder in c#

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to create a zip folder in c#.

This is my destination where I need to have my zip.
string zippath = @"C:\Neenu\Download";
Below is my code to convert it as ZIP.

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"" + startPath, @"" + zippath);
```

My start path is

```
C:\\Users\\spfarm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1neplbgk.qj3\\ilty Management System -SCM-2016-39.docx
```

I am getting error as access to path is denied. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please clean up your question, unless you really meant that your startpath variable contains the following text at the end: " and zippath is C:\Neenu\Download.".

Comment: Use the stratpath as directory instead of file name `string startpath = @"C:\Users\spfarm\AppData\Local\\Temp\1neplbgk.qj3\";`

Comment: Also set the zippath as a file name instead of directory `string zippath = @"C:\Test\Sample.zip";`

Comment: Thank you. Actually I want to zip the entire folder 1neplbgk.qj3 inside the download folder. Message = "Access to the path 'C:\\Neenu\\Download' is denied." I got this meesage now.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to ensure we can see exactly the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a complete example of how to compress a file using your code, you should **clean up your variables and make sure that your paths are correct.**

When it comes to accessing your C drive, there might be a permission problem, in that case you could try to **run the program as administrator in order to get full (read/write depends on your needs) access to the drive** as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304191/access-to-the-path-c-users-xxx-desktop-is-denied)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;    

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string startPath = @"C:\Users\spfarm\AppData\Local\Temp
                             \1neplbgk.qj3\ilty Management System -SCM-2016-39.docx";
        string zipPath = @"c:\result.zip";

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
}
```